# countdown timer for statically generated sites

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, static-site-generation

I think I have hit a limitation of statically generated sites. I am using Gatsby to statically generate pages. To generate these pages:

- data is pulled from CMS where we configure end time for the countdown timer, say, in next two days.
- since pages are generated today, after two days, users who access these pages, see this countdown timer for a moment and then it goes away as logic to calculate countdown timer values kicks in and figures out that it is expired and need not be shown.

What this means is there is layout shift since countdown timer no longer exists and whole page moves up. If I choose to build the page in a way that calculation to shown/hide countdown timer is done only on client side, then in case countdown timer needs to be shown, everything moves down and again there is layout shift. Requirement is to show this at the top of the page and we can't put this at the top of other elements like promotional banners/popup you see all over internet.

Any idea what we can do here to avoid this layout shift.

Comment: If you want to create a banner/pop up just create a React.createPortal component and potentially for reusablility and to prevent any prop drilling in the future, add it to a global state like context/redux. This will nest it outside of the virtual DOM even if including into a nested level of the component tree.

Comment: Otherwise an alternative is to just show a loading spinner inbetween the state change of the countdown -> page compononet swap out to prevent a layout shift. By the sounds of the "layout shifting" it sounds like you're hiding the countdown component AFTER the content is being loaded in, so the content appears then shifts up after the component removes. So you may want to edit your logic so that the countdown is removed then the page appears.

Comment: option 1 is against the requirement as we don't want promotional banner to be a pop up. It should simply show up at the top till the promo ends. About second option, wouldn't it hit FCP score for lighthouse.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue before and solved it in a dirty way; you can hide the body and fade it in when the countdown timer script has been loaded.

Like so:

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script>
    document.body.className = 'hidden';
</script>

<img src="https://picsum.photos/2000" />


<script>
(function() {
  function c() {
    document.body.className = document.body.className.replace("hidden", "visible")
    }
  document.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener("load", c, !1) : document.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload", c)
})();
</script>
```

Another solution would be to make sure there is always something of the same size behind the countdown timer. So that, in the event that it doesn't show, it shows something else in the same spot.

Comment: As you rightly said, first solution would be be considered bad practice.  Second solution is something I did consider but but might not work for us as we use this countdown timer in promotional banner which would not always exist. So we cannot have anything that is always there and which sometimes is ok to be overlapped with promotional banner. But thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Actually, I just looked at the site I'm doing this on, and it seems like the first solution has a positive impact on my lighthouse score (FCP of 0.3s). As long as the script loads fast enough, it's not an issue. I hide the body using javascript and then fade it in when everything has loaded. This way someone without javascript enabled can still access the site.